# "Error running com.example.flutter_launcher. Default activity not found" after changing AndroidManifest

Tags: android, flutter, android-manifest

I added this 2 lines in AndroidManifest.

```xml
<category android:name="android.intent.action.DEFAULT" />
<category android:name="android.intent.action.HOME" />
```

Now I get this error, even after reverting the changes.

```
Error running com.example.flutter_launcher. Default activity not found
Unable to read manifest info from D:\src\flutter_launcher\build\app\outputs\apk\app.apk.
No application found for TargetPlatform.android_x86.
Is your project missing an android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml?
Consider running "flutter create ." to create one.
```

I ran "flutter create ." with no luck.

Comment: please also try to add these two intent filters for your main activity "<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>"

Comment: Have you tried maybe flutter clean and flutter build apk?
I can see that the one of the errors says "Unable to read manifest info from D:\src\flutter_launcher\build\app\outputs\apk\app.apk.
N".

Comment: I already had the 2 lines mentioned by @android included.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Deleting `D:\src\flutter_launcher\build\app\outputs\apk\app.apk` worked for me.

Looks like Android Studio detects that it's missing and rebuilds it. This issue is likely caused because you opened a second Android Studio for platform integration with the Android platform, and the Flutter Android Studio didn't detect a manifest change and didn't rebuild the APK.

Comment: It's a little late, but thanks for your reply. I already gave up because I couldn't figure it out. I'll try this later and let you know if it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I fix this problem with :

1. flutter clean
2. flutter pub get

Answer (score 0):

I used the above solution still was getting issues of `manifest` not found or default activity then I removed code which I have added in manifest and separately open the android folder and made changes in it and run the app from there. It worked.